# Pygame Error when trying to display a line of text from a list TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

```
              for i in magicList:
                    enemyName = myfont.render(enemy.name,1,(255,255,255))
                    number = []
                    number.append(i)
                    pos = len(number)
                    mDisplayText=myfont.render((str(pos, i)),1,(255,255,255))
```

I am trying to display on screen every item from the list 'magicList' as well as a number in front of that indicating the position so it would look someting like this

1) Fireball

2) Explosion

3) Heal

I have been able to display it with just the text but i can't seem to do it with the numbers, is my use of the len flawed or is it something else because everytime it try that it returns the error:

```
    mDisplayText=myfont.render((str(pos, i)),1,(255,255,255))
    TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes
```

it's weird that its like this considering pos *should* be an integer, but if anyone knows what's wrong here i'd love to know.

---

For anyone that is asking why i don't just do it without the numbers, I have to use the numbers because that is how the player will select it, doing this way means i can append a potentially infinite number of items to the list without having to pre-program them all.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `str(pos, i)`? If you want to convert both `pos` and `i` then do it separately (`str(pos) + str(i)`). `str` only takes one argument to convert to string, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str

Comment: I know that already and have made amends in the actual code, that was just leftovers from testing anyway since regardless it returns a type error

Comment: The `TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes` gets raised because you pass something else than a string to `.render`. The code snippet in your post raises a different error. Always post your actual code [(a verifiable example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise you make it difficult for us to help you to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the len function, I have seen below in the documentation, please see this, it is not obvious to say with out looking at your data, hence sharing this info.

> Null characters (‘x00’) raise a TypeError. Both Unicode and char (byte) strings are accepted. For Unicode strings only UCS-2 characters (‘u0001’ to ‘uFFFF’) are recognized. Anything greater raises a UnicodeError.

See this link for more info https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html

One more thing I also suspect casting "str(pos, i) ", because I tried below lines to rule out the root cause and ended up having error "    print(str(pos, i))
TypeError: coercing to str: need a bytes-like object, int found"

```
i ='Some text'
pos =2
print(str(pos, i))
```

Comment: Doing str() was probably a bad idea, but the list is just a list of strings and pos should just be a number, so their is no Null Characters or anything like that